# Python set mutations : AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'k'

Tags: python-3.x, set

I have to actually solve the problem in the image. But I am unable to get why it is generating attribute error. can someone please explain what it means and how it can be avoided in my code.[[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkKwT.png)]

```
A= int(input())
set1=set(map(int,input().split()))
N=int(input())
for i in range(N):
    k,*a=input().split()
    set2=set(map(int,input().split()))
    set1.k(set2)

print(sum(set1))
```

Comment: Where have you seen that `set` has a `k` method ??? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: k is an update operation that is taken from user . so i want to use that operation on set1 and set2. can you please open the problem image,

Answer (score 0):

set1.k(set2). what are you trying to do here?
If you want to update or add use:

```
set1.add(set2)
set1.update(set2)
```

Comment: k is an update operation that is taken from input . so i want to use that operation on set1 and set2